# Nested for loop for letter matrix output

Tags: javascript, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops, letter

**Background:** I've been working on nested for loop exercises. The program I'm writing is meant to take column and row data and create a letter matrix or grid using a nested for loop. I was able to get the data to compile in a grid (great!) but there is a line of unnecessary data stuck on top of the grid.(not so great...) Can anyone let me know what could be causing this, I believe it is something extremely simple but my brain is likely fried from looking at this for so long.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: photo of unwanted textline]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>""</title>

    <script>
        function letter_matrix() {

            let column = parseInt(document.form.letter_column.value);
            let rows = parseInt(document.form.letter_rows.value);
            let text = "<table><th></th>";

            let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            

            for (let i = 0; i < rows ; ++i) {
             
             text += "<tr>"+ letters.charAt(i) + "</td>";

               for(let j = 0; j < column ; j++){
                
                   let k = (i * rows + j) % 26;

                   text += "<td>"+letters.charAt(k)+ "</td>";
               }

               
        }
        text += "</table>";
 
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= text;
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>""</h1>

    <form name="form" action = "javascript:letter_matrix();">

        Columns: <input type="text" name="letter_column">
        Rows: <input type="text" name="letter_rows">

        <input type="submit" value="Enter values.">

    </form>

    <pre id="results">
    </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you mean this?  <h1>""</h1>

Comment: no, he means there is another row out of the matrix rendered

Comment: actually, you should always put the <script> in <body > or after <body>, not in <head> cuz it will block page rendering. There are a few exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `for` you create a `<tr>` add some text and close a `</td>`.

You should most likely just open a `tr` and after the inner `for` then close the `tr`

```js
for (let i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  text += "<tr>";
  for (let j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    let k = (i * rows + j) % 26;
    text += "<td>" + letters.charAt(k) + "</td>";
  }
  text += '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split `<tr>` tag like shown below. This line is causing issue

`text += "<tr>"+ letters.charAt(i) + "</td>";`

The abnormal result you are getting is because of that only. See code below how I used `</tr>` after the **`for`** loop and removed **`letter.charAt(i)`**. This was adding that extra row.

```
         text += "<tr>";
        
           for(let j = 0; j < column ; j++){
            
               let k = (i * rows + j) % 26;
        
               text += "<td>"+letters.charAt(k)+ "</td>";
           }
         text += "</tr>";
```

Refer the working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3tf7egw5/)

Answer (score 0):

This is it.
https://jsfiddle.net/Cornel777/kgbojuhz/8/

1. Just added `"<td>"` here `text += "<tr>"+ "<td>" + letters.charAt(i) + "</td>";`
2. Moved your `<script>` after `<body>`
3. Did this but it is not mandatory, just newer.

`let column = document.getElementById("columns").value;`

`let rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <title>""</title>
    
      
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>""</h1>
    
        <form name="form" action = "javascript:letter_matrix();">
    
            Columns: <input id="columns" type="text" name="letter_column">
            Rows: <input id="rows" type="text" name="letter_rows">
    
            <input type="submit" value="Enter values.">
    
        </form>
    
        <pre id="results">
        </pre>
    </body>
    
      <script>
            function letter_matrix() {
    
                let column = document.getElementById("columns").value;
                let rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
                let text = "<table><th></th>";
    
                let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                
    
                for (let i = 0; i < rows ; i++) {
                 
                 text += "<tr>"+ "<td>" + letters.charAt(i) + "</td>";
    
                   for(let j = 0; j < column ; j++){
                   
                
                       let k = (i * rows + j) % 26;
    
                       text += "<td>"+letters.charAt(k)+ "</td>";
                   }
    
                   
            }
            
            text += "</table>";
     
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= text;
        }
        </script>
    
    </html>
    
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2gn.png
```